# How to run a remote container in JetBrains IDE

Tags: docker, containers, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider, remote-containers

Please forgive me as this is my first time working with docker and containers so I may mess up some terminology.

So I am trying to take on a project that is found in a remote docker container, and as far as I know, working remotely in a container is only offered in VSCode. I am more comfortable with JetBrains products and would like to move over there, but I can’t figure a way to configure the environment onto the IDE.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html

Comment: That’s for just using a container within jetbrains IDE and not working in it remotely. For instance, if I run the container I am still not working in the container

Comment: You can add a remote Docker server and manage remote containers

Comment: How do you go about doing that?  How do I know what the server is from looking at the container

Comment: If you can access Docker remotely, it means that it exposes its API. So add that into section 2 (TCP). Everything else is in the link that I sent (how to connect, how to build, how to run, etc).

Comment: Ok so yeah I am completely lost. To simplify what I am trying to replicate on rider is that you know how when you have a container for a project on vscode, and then vscode states "Folder contains a dev container configuration file, reopen in container to develop in a container" That is what I am trying to replicate on Rider. Thank you so much and I apologize for this! I am new to containers